# Why does Android debug mode delete my application preferences?

Tags: android, debugging, for-loop, mono, sharedpreferences

When I start my application in debug on my virtual device (and also on my HTC Desire HD) all is working okay. I fill in my preferences and save them. They are saved on the internal storage of the device belonging to my app. When I leave the app and restart it, my preferences are still there. But when I change my code a little bit and start the debugger again, my app is being uninstalled and again installed. Because of the uninstallment my preferences are deleted too.

I don't want my preferences to be deleted. What am I doing wrong? Is it impossible to save my preferences?

I am using Mono for Android 3.0.4.6 and Visual Studio 2010 with Mono for Android addin 40206. Please help because every time I start the debugger I have to fill in my preferences.

Answer (score 1):

If you reinstall your app all data will be delete.
You can try to automatize process of filling your apllication probably with `monkeyrunner`.

Comment: Yeah. Apps installed with a Debug or Release key have different signatures, which means the app has to get uninstalled first. However, you can install a new version of an app which has the same signature with the `-r` flag using `adb install -r appname.apk`, which will preserve preferences and other data